# Tracking Instagram Hashtag number of posts using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

I have been searching for a way to retrieve information about the number of hashtags used for some names.

I'd like to take the information like the picture below.

An example, I'd like to search for hashtags like "food", "foodporn", "foodpicture" and more.

I already found a script but doesn't use API and after a moment it blocks the website to try to retrieve the information.

[image]

Comment: Try [this](https://rapidapi.com/blog/instagram-api-python/) or [this](https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api).

Comment: thank you @Armadillan, for sure I'll take a look, thanks for your time